# iOS: Detect when finger is on TouchID home button

Tags: ios, touch-id

I want to use the iPhone's fingerprint sensor to detect when a finger is on the home button in my app. I was thinking of using TouchID and letting it pass or fail; either way, I'll know that a finger is on the home button.

I read [here](https://www.secsign.com/fingerprint-validation-as-an-alternative-to-passcodes/) that you can use TouchID authentication in an iOS app with the following, but it shows a modal window and everything to ask for authentication, which is not what I want. I just want a callback when a finger is placed on the home button.

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
[context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"Authenticate for server login" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *authenticationError){
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Fingerprint validated.");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Fingerprint validation failed: %@.", authenticationError.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

[image: The offending window]

Comment: I am not aware of any public APIs that provide details on the presence of a finger on the Touch ID sensor.

Comment: Neither I am. Is that even useful?

Comment: Maybe detecting finger presence is niche, but I'd think someone might want to take TouchID authentication with a custom dialog (or no dialog) instead of Apple's provided one.

Comment: Would be nice if one wants to start touchId automatically when a certain view is visible and the user touches the home button. This should be possible since Apple can detect a double touch to pull the content down on big screens.